# Anyone knows the fonts used in this Resume?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I found a really creative resume when I was surfing the web this morning, and it uses some awesome sans-serif typefaces, but I don't know the fonts. Has anyone seen them before? (WhatTheFont was no help)

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like [**Aller**](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/daltonmaag/aller-typo/) by Dalton Maag.

Samples:

[image]

[image]

I think all the text on the page is the same font, but in varying weights.

The broken R, K and X make it distinctive and at first I thought it may have been [Klavika](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/processtype/klavika/) (also known as "The Facebook font") which also has those features, but it clearly isn't.

Note: as pointed out to me in the comments, there is a free version of Aller.  "Aller Typo" is the paid version.

PS. By the way, if this is a real resume, he really needs someone to rewrite the opening paragraph as it's full of mistakes and sounds very amateur.  It implies he's only ever designed one site, and it was for a friend, and that he doesn't think it was very good.  And since he claims to be a graphic designer, there are all sorts of inconsistencies with font sizes such as "MOBILE NUMBER" / "EMAIL ADDRESS".  And there are spelling errors like "COMPUTER INGENEERING [sic]".  And what does "CHELSEA FC" have to do with it?  It's not explained.

Comment: Haha, yeah I noticed that myself, looks like english isn't his first language. Nice layout though.

Comment: It's more likely Aller Standard, whuich is free: http://www.daltonmaag.com/buyonline/fonts/aller

Comment: Good point.  I guess the Typo edition probably has fancier typographic features like many more glyphs, ligatures, kerning, and/or other things - which aren't necessarily needed.

Comment: To be fair to the guy, it does say "English (intermediate)" so there's no false advertising (though someone with high indesign skills should know how to switch spellcheck on and change its language). That said, part of me really wants to add a line under "Creativity: [10/10]" saying "Modesty: [4/10]", but I guess all is fair in war and resumes. CV / resume conventions vary by culture: in the UK, a slight personal touch like including non-work passions like Chelsea and travelling alongside work related passions would be well received (but, here, photos in CVs are usually frowned on)