# Microsoft Word Strength Meter

Tags: information-graphics, microsoft-word

I have no idea if this should be created here but I have a simple question, anyone knows how to generate a skill strength meter similar to the one shown below

[image: Found Here]

All the help is really appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use an icon font that has suitable icons with "on"/"off" states (or just use the same icon with e.g. differing colors). Using a font means it's as simple as installing the font and typing (or inserting via character map etc if needs be) the relevant icons.

Here is an example using [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/)...

[image]

*(Example is in Illustrator, but that's irrelevant; all you need to do is install the font.)*

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, thank you very much

Comment: @Cai: i recently started using FA for InDesign work and it is... awesome :) But i find i annoying when looking for an icon i have to browse through everything via the Glyphs panel. Any way to type a FA character by its unicode number?

Comment: @Lucian no idea sorry, I just use the glyphs panel (as you can see from my screenshot :)

Comment: @Lucian you can do it the same way as in any other application its a operating system feature (so in windows you hold alt gr and type the number in the num pad). Also you can collect the glyphs you use frequently into a custom palette

Answer (score 2):

There's a 99% chance Microsoft Word was not used to create that. Word is not adept at handling detailed layout intricacies and is most often not used by professional designers when they create their resumes.

As for the meter... it's just circles. Draw a row of circles.. fill some in. That's all there is to it. These types of "meters" are **not** actually based on any form of scientific data or quantitate studies. They are random, ambiguous visuals, that's all.

(How a native English speaker can only score a 9 out of 10 in "English Language" is a mystery to me -- are there days where he can't speak English???)

See Also:

[Is having a skills bar chart on a resume a good idea?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15488/is-having-a-skills-bar-chart-on-a-resume-a-good-idea)

And

[Is a graphical/original resume a good idea for a designer?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5906/is-a-graphical-original-resume-a-good-idea-for-a-designer)

Comment: Hello Metis,  
What you are saying is correct, those are not based on scientific methods, but let's be real and believe me, if your CV looks nice, you are already that much closer to grabbing that interview. I am a very well experienced Information Security Professional and I am not even getting a chance for an interview in some companies just because my CV is straight up technical and normal. I am looking to add those measures of course with the needed details to have it look better. I know word does not provide it but I was looking for a generator as I tried drawing circles and it was ugly

Comment: I was looking to create something similar to those https://enhancv.com/

Comment: Uhm.. then sign up at that site. Sorry, but no one here is going to create a resume for you or make you a tutorial on how to create a resume. That's not what this site is for.

Comment: I know this, and of course, I am not asking anyone to create a resume for me as I already created my template, filled it, designed it and all that is missing is just those dotted circles and strength meters.

Answer (score 1):

Most fonts have a 'bullet' character built in (`alt-8` if you're on a mac, not sure for PC) or you can find a symbol font with a nice circle in it (such as `m` in Zapf Dingbats) to create a row of circles. Then add a stroke to them using the Format Text Effects / Text Line options in word. Once you have created your master set of icons with spacing and sizing that you like, it's then just a matter of making some of them white and some of them black (or whatever colour you like), as required for representing your skill levels.

[image]