# How to show add number of years to the skills section on a resume

Tags: resume

I have my primary skills listed as follow on resume (example),

[image: Example]

I want to make it more i̶n̶t̶e̶r̶a̶c̶t̶i̶n̶g̶  to the point and show the exact information recruiter wants to see e.g. number of years for each skill.

Anyone could think of interactive way of adding number of years and how ?

Edit:

At the present it's just a picture, but I can use photoshop, gimp, word etc.. to make it look like anyway I want.

Comment: Not an answer, but my first thoughts on that graph. All skills have a grade from 'useless' to 'absolute perfection'. No-one is 'absolutely perfect' at anything, so already it looks like you're bragging on some skills. As for the others, who would employ anyone who isn't 'absolutely perfect' at all of them. I think it's a terrible idea, & I'm sorry if that comes out harsh, but I think you'd be far better off just listing your skills in text, with durations as part of the paragraph. Let them decide if that makes you 'close to perfection' for the skillset they're looking for.

Comment: Are we talking HTML, XML, Windows app, Linux app, mobile app (Android/iPhone)?  As asked by Tetsujin, above, what is the sliding scale represnetitive of?

Comment: In my experience of interviewing/hiring creatives, I find lists like these pretty useless. In a resume I want to see is what you have achieved , not what you think you are good at. If I think your achievements are suitable, you'll get an interview where we will discuss those achievements and the skills you used to do so. Wow them with the resume, show them how you did it in the interview.

Comment: @JacksonHyde that's sensible, but not something recruiting agents do, infact they don't even understand the techs at all in most cases, so they rely on number of years one has worked with something

Comment: @Mathematics That's why you include your employment history with a brief overview of responsibilities for each entry.

Comment: I've been playing the piano for over 20 years and I'm really bad at it. Years on a resume are really not that meaningful... Unless this is something specifically requested by a recruiter, I think you would be much better off getting a recommandation letter from previous colleagues on how well you can handle X and Y.

Comment: Please [edit] this to explain if its for a website or print. It appears to be about print but more than once you ask about making it interactive.

Answer (score 5):

Related: [Is having a skills bar chart on a resume a good idea?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15488/is-having-a-skills-bar-chart-on-a-resume-a-good-idea)

Such graphs are largely pointless.

If you want to show experience in specific areas, then list things with *actual* usable information:

- Public speaking since 1990
- Google Analytics since 1996
- Email marketing since 2005
- Sales since 2003
- Research & Strategy since 2010

If you want to show such data in a visual, then use **actual** quantifiable information.

[image]

This way the visual *actually* means something. In addition, there's no "subjective" stance on what *you* think *you* are good at. It's merely hard, cold, numbers... years doing something. It's assumed by most that the longer you do something the better you are at that ability. Let the *subtext* express your level of skill, don't try to pull it off with a pretty bar chart or anything.

There *are* some areas that simply make you look **worse** because they are included -- Emotional Intelligence, Decision Making, Negotiation?? How would these *ever* be measured? Including these nonsensical "skills" merely makes it appear as "puffing" and I would *absolutely* be uncertain how much "puffing" there is in *other* areas. Meaning, once I saw a silly skill such as "emotional intelligence" I would *entirely* dismiss *everything* in that area.